# How to change font style of abstract and acknowledgements in table of content in memoir?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, memoir, abstract, acknowledgements

I'm writing my M.Sc. Thesis with latex in `memoir`. I have some problems with the abstract and acknowledgements environments. When adding `\abstractintoc` in the preamble, both appear in the ToC, which is great, because this is what my professor wants. But, the font  of those two in the ToC is different (picture below). I found and tried many things, but nothing seems to help my problem. This is the code that i use for the Abstract:

```
{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily\textcolor{dshs}{Abstract}}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would really have helped if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to something like `\chapter{...} \end{document}`) showing what you had done. The following is therefore a guess in the dark about a possible fix for your problem --- you only showed the result, not how you got to it. (Actually I am following the request to be nice. --- GOM[image])

```
% memabstocprob.tex  SE 600887
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

% no idea where \textcolor{dshs} comes from
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily%\textcolor{dshs}
  {Abstract}}
%\abstractintoc % adds \abstractname into the ToC

\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} % just adds Abstract into the ToC
THE ABSTRACT TEXT.
\end{abstract}

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}
\section{one}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This actually helped me :) I'm sorry for not providing an MWE. I'm using a thesis template which is quite complex and i thought adding everything from there would've been too much. Thanks anyway!